# How to solve $U_{n+1}=U_n+\frac{2}{n(n+2)}D_n, D_{n+1}=U_{n+1}+D_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came to this sequence $(U_n, D_n)$ starting from $(U_1, D_1)$ with $U_1=D_1=T$ and

$$\begin{pmatrix}U_{n+1}\\D_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&\frac{2}{n(n+2)}\\1&1+\frac{2}{n(n+2)}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}U_n\\D_n\end{pmatrix}$$

Or,

$$U_{n+1}=U_n+\frac{2}{n(n+2)}D_n$$
$$D_{n+1}=U_{n+1}+D_n$$

How to generate a general formula for $(U_n, D_n)$? More generally, is there some trick in such series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think i got it.

Let $$T_n=\frac{n}{n+1}U_n+\frac{1}{n+1}D_n$$

One has $T_{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{n}T_n$, hence $$T_n=nT$$

Eliminating $U_n$ out one has

$$D_{n+1}=(n+1)T+\frac{n+1}{n+2}D_n$$

Drive this to $D_1$ one has

$$D_n=\frac{n(n+2)}{3}T$$

and hence $$U_n=\frac{2n+1}{3}T$$